# R strsplit, nested lists blues

Tags: r, string, list, nested-lists, strsplit

I am facing this issue in R in which I want to split the strings on comma and then further split on semicolon, but only keep the first item before the semicolon i.e. ee and jj below. I have tried a bunch of things but nested lists seem too convoluted!

Here's what I am doing:

```
d <- c("aa,bb,cc,dd,ee;e,ff",
       "gg,hh,ii,jj;j")

e=strsplit(d,",")
myfun2 <- function(x,arg1) {
 strsplit(x,";")
}
f=lapply(e,myfun2)
f=
 [[1]]
 [[1]][[1]]
 [1] "aa"

 [[1]][[2]]
 [1] "bb"

 [[1]][[3]]
 [1] "cc"

 [[1]][[4]]
 [1] "dd"

 [[1]][[5]]
 [1] "ee" "e" 

 [[1]][[6]]
 [1] "ff"

 [[2]]
 [[2]][[1]]
 [1] "gg"

 [[2]][[2]]
 [1] "hh"

 [[2]][[3]]
 [1] "ii"

 [[2]][[4]]
 [1] "jj" "j"
```

Here's the output that I want

```
Correct output=
[[1]]
[1] "aa" "bb" "cc" "dd" "ee" "ff"

[[2]]
[1] "gg" "hh" "ii" "jj"
```

I have tried a bunch of things using lapply to the nested list "f" and used "[[" and "[" but with no success.

Any help is greatly appreciated. (I know that I am missing something silly, but just can't figure it out right now!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your code

```
d <- c("aa,bb,cc,dd,ee;e,ff", "gg,hh,ii,jj;j")
e <- strsplit(d,",")
myfun2 <- function(x,arg1) { strsplit(x,";") }
f <- lapply(e,myfun2)
```

If we start from your `f`, then the next step would be

```
lapply(f,function(x) mapply(`[`,x,1))
```

```
[[1]]
[1] "aa" "bb" "cc" "dd" "ee" "ff"

[[2]]
[1] "gg" "hh" "ii" "jj"
```

Basically, you need an inner and outer type apply function to go down the two levels of nesting.

Comment: Perfect! This was just what I wanted. Have never used mapply!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `gsub` to match the pattern `;` followed by one ore more alphabetic characters, replace with `''`, and then split (`strsplit`) with `,`.

```
strsplit(gsub(';[a-z]+', '', d), ',')
#[[1]]
#[1] "aa" "bb" "cc" "dd" "ee" "ff"

#[[2]]
#[1] "gg" "hh" "ii" "jj"
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I tried gsub. The above example is a stylized example. Actually, I can have strings of "aa__;bb__;zz__" and so on and some of them don't even have to be an alphabet and can be numeric. So, the regex pattern to match can be really complex.

Comment: Ok. I apologize. I think I will figure out the relevant regex for the task and accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @BladeRunner It's okay.  If you can show some example and update in the post, I will try to answer it.

Comment: The solution below is better and doesn't depend on explicit regex matching.

Comment: @BladeRunner Okay, no problem.